# Exponential Word Problem s(x)=5000−4000e^(−x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sales of a new model of word processor are approximated by S(x)=5000−4000e^(−x), where x represents the number of years that the word processor has been on the market, and S(x) represents sales in thousands of dollars. When will sales reach 4,500,000?

Comment: @RossMillikan Why should s(x) be integrated ? That´s not true-in my opinon. I agree with the answer of Christian Gaetz. And who marked your comment as useful ?

Comment: @callculus:  I was reading the problem to ask for cumulative sales, not sales rate, which is where the integral came from.  Rereading, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

We need to solve the equation $$5000-4000e^{-x} = 4,500$$ for $x$.  Let's get the constants on one side: $$-4000e^{-x}=-500$$ and then divide both sides by -4000: $$e^{-x}=\frac{-500}{-4000}=\frac{1}{8}$$  Now, how do we get variables out of the exponent?  Try using logarithms.